Proverbs 8:30 - Doesn't "I will be..." make better sense than "I was...?"
Proverbs 8:30 (NJPS)

I was with him as a confident, a source of delight every day, rejoicing before Him at all times
ואהיה אצלו אמון ואהיה שׁעשׁעים יום יום משׂחקת לפניו בּכל־עת

The verse begins ואהיה, which all translations understand as and-I-was.
Elsewhere, the same expression is understood as and-I-will be
Genesis 26:3

Sojourn in this land, and I will be ואהיה with you and will bless you, for to you and to your offspring I will give all these lands, and I will establish the oath that I swore to Abraham your father.

Genesis 31:3

Then the LORD said to Jacob, “Return to the land of your fathers and to your kindred, and I will be ואהיה with you.”

If ואהיה is understood as in Genesis, we get:

I will be with Him as a confident. I will be a delight every day, rejoicing before him at all times.

In this way Proverbs is describing the relationship between wisdom and God after creation.
Doesn't "I will be..." make better sense than "I was...?"

"I will be" would only make better sense if the verse speaks of the quality of wisdom only relating to God at, and after, creation. There's something obviously absurd about that, for it would indicate that God did not relate to wisdom prior to creation, suggesting that God created without wisdom.
There's no doubt amongst Christians that wisdom was magnificently displayed by God both at creation, and after creation. However, wisdom cannot be at anybody's side, literally. As a quality, it has to be intrinsic to the one who has it. The idea that God was without wisdom until creation began is nonsense. However, an appeal is then made to how the phrase in question is used in Genesis, claiming this supports how the phrase should be used in Proverbs 8. It is on the basis of ancient Hebrew translation that the case is made for wisdom relating to God at creation (and thereafter). So, what is to be made of that?
Here is what one literal translation of the Proverbs passage makes of it. Note also how verse 24 speaks of this wisdom being 'brought forth', as in the sense of 'displayed' or 'demonstrated', not created at a certain point in time:

" Jehovah possessed me - the beginning of his way, Before His works
since then. From the age I was anointed, from the first, from former
states of the earth. In there being no depths, I was brought forth. In
there being no fountains heavy [with] waters. Before mountains were
sunk, before heights, I was brought forth. While He had not made
the earth, and out-places, and the top of the dusts of the world.
In his preparing the heavens I [am] there, in His decreeing a circle
on the face of the deep... Then I am near Him, a workman, and I am a
delight - day by day. Rejoicing before Him at all times." Proverbs
8:22-30 Young's Literal Translation [emphasis mine]

The translator, Robert Young, has a lengthy explanation of "the Battle of the Hebrew Tenses", his use of them, and Analysis of the Verbs in Genesis ix. 12-15 from page VI of the introduction. The Genesis verses in the question are not included. Then he details reasons for "Waw Conversive" A Fiction" and The Waw Conversive - Imperfect.
The conjunction 'and' is 'waw' in Hebrew, a very common opinion being that it can have a conversive power, and that the verb is not to be translated 'past' (though so in grammatical form), but 'future'. Young goes on to say that this "is only an evasion of the supposed difficulty, not a solution, and requires to be supported by the equally untenable hypothesis that a (so-called) future tense, when preceded by the same conjunction waw ("and,") often becomes a past. Notwithstanding these two converting hypotheses, there are numerous passages which have no conjunction before them, which can only be explained by the principles stated above." page V
This is followed by  Young comparing Hebrew tenses with Rabbinical writings, Samaritan, ancient Ethiopic, Amharic, Maltese, Coptic, ancient then modern Arabic, ancient then modern Syriac, Turkish, Persian, Sanscrit, Gujarati, Hindustani, Siamese, Teloogoo, Malav, New Zealand, and English.
One of his conclusions is that "the Waw Conversive does not exist in the Hebrew Bible, and is unnecessary, imperfect, and unexampled in any language." (page XIV) Just mentioning this might create eruptions on this site, so all I will say is that anyone wanting to understand Young's use of Hebrew tenses in both Genesis and Proverbs, needs to study his lengthy explanatory preface. Then they will see why he consistently avoids "I will be" in the Proverbs 8 passage.

Thank you. Very detailed. One thing I think you might consider is the difference between God's wisdom which, obviously is inherent and always present, and wisdom personified as an entity distinct from God.

@RevelationLad  I was brought up with the belief of wisdom personified as an entity distinct from God, which was why I detailed "verse 24 speaks of this wisdom being 'brought forth', as in the sense of 'displayed' or 'demonstrated', not created at a certain point in time". I believe in Christ being "the wisdom of God" (1 Cor.1:24) but he is not "an entity distinct from God"!

Those who deny the deity of Christ use this passage to support the idea Christ was created. To the extent it is understood as an entity apart from God, that misinterpretation is possible. OTOH if wisdom is inherent to God then it shouldn't be tossed about as if something apart from God.

@RevelationLad  Just so.

The context supports a waw consecutive thus a past tense translation.
           When he established the heavens, I was there; 
  when he drew a circle on the face of the deep, 
        28       when he made firm the skies above, 
  when he established the fountains of the deep, 
        29       when he assigned to the sea its limit, 
  so that the waters might not transgress his command, 
              when he marked out the foundations of the earth, 
                             (Prov. 8:27–29, ESV)


Whenever the imperfect form is preceeded by a waw it may be a waw consecutive or waw copulative.
--
Van der Merwe, C., Naudé, J., Kroeze, J., Van der Merwe, C., Naudé, J., & Kroeze, J. (1999). A Biblical Hebrew Reference Grammar (electronic ed., pp. 71–76). Sheffield Academic Press.

The imperfect tense means incomplete action and tends to have a future meaning.  A waw copulative means the waw is a conjunction without changing the meaning of the verb.  However, in the Hebrew Bible when a waw is preposition to an imperfect verb, the waw consecutive is far more common and is usually translated as past tense as if it were perfect tense, meaning completed action.  Translating a waw consecutive as past tense is not controversial.  However, it being equivalent to a perfect tense is debated.

The OP is correct to the extent that both verbs in Gen 26:3 and Prov 8:30 are וְאֶֽהְיֶ֥ה which is Qal-imperfect.
However, (and this is a big "but") there is no tense in Hebrew verbs - such must be inferred by the context.  These two verses are discussing different events:

Prov 8:30 is recounting a past event and the personification of wisdom and how wisdom was by God's side during the creation of the universe - a past event
Gen 26:3 is a prophecy about the future - God promises to bless Jacob and always be with him in the future.

Thus, it is entirely proper that these notionally identical (grammatically) verbs be translated with opposite tenses: one past and the other future.

Do you believe wisdom is not at God's side after creation? A present condition?

@RevelationLad - of course - wisdom is an inalienable condition of God.  BUT - Prov 8 id describing a past event - the fact that was always with God from the creation of the world.
